# UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage reduces image size

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, swift3, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm having an issue with `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage`: it returns the original photo while reducing its quality. For instance, the original photo may have a size of 3264x2448 or even 1920x1440, but once it's returned by `imagePickerController` the image has a size of 640x480.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        print("image size: \(image.size)")
    }
}
```

Since I enabled `allowsEditing=true`, the user can edit the image (crop/resize, native iOS functionality) while picking a photo. But even when the photo is not being edited by the user, the picker is reducing the image size. I don't know why.

I tried using `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key, and I got the original photo, which is fine as it returns the original photo & image size (3264x2448 or 1920x1440).

I need to allow the user edit the photo without loosing quality nor reducing the image size.

How can I get the original image size & quality for the edited image?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get
 if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
}

Comment: that's what I said, @jignesh...